# How do I compile & use java-dbus 2.7 on windows?

Tags: java, cross-platform, dbus

If I'm working on a cross-platform project that uses dbus-java, what do I need to do differently on windows?

[This](http://old.nabble.com/dbus-java-binding---microsoft-windows-td33027997.html) is the only resource I've found that asks this question, and I'm not sure I understand the answer. Do I really need to write my own TCP bus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can just use the linux jar files, as long as you connect over TCP. 
You also need to run your own dbus-daemon to connect to, since windows doesn't automatically have one.

Comment: If someone wants to post a more detailed answer, or explain how to compile dbus-java on windows, I'm still open to other answers.